# Is there any approach how to test Spring Transactions propagations

Tags: java, spring, testing

Is it possible to implement test covers propagations provided by spring transaction infrastructure, like REQUIRES_NEW, REQUIRED, etc.

In fact, Spring provides TestTransaction which is more skimp comparing with regular Transaction in production. Here is the reference for that https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-test-managed-transactions

Also, playing with events, callbacks doesn't give desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this sort of things you need to create integration tests, e.g. tests which leverage a test database deployment and verify if the transactional mechanism properly implemented.